# Failed to call remote function module with SAP and .NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, saprfc

I was using .NET for development an SAP application but recently, it always shows me the message below:

> failed to call remote function module

I didn't change any setting or source code. But it still has the problem.

Anyone can tell me how to solve?

Comment: Did you try to debug? What does code look like where the error occurs? [Stack Overflow is not a Mind Reader](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128551/143302). Please update your question and provide more details or it will likely get closed.

Comment: you should have a look at the stack trace, there is probably a more descriptive exception with an error message that points in the right direction.

Comment: Ensure that the sap account used for this RFC is still active.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you communicate the problem with the sap dev team? Make sure the function module is working correctly and it's remote call enabled.
Is there a firewall between you .NET application and sap system? Make sure port 3301(I'm not sure about port number, please find it in sap jco document) is open on firewall.